# Oracle to SQL Server (converting from character string)

Tags: sql, sql-server

This code works in Oracle, but it's failing in SQL server.  I'm brand new to SQL server and am not sure what the correct way to remedy this is.

```
SELECT CASE GROUPING(HireDate)
        when 0 then HireDate
        else 'TOTAL'
   end HireDate,
   count(HireDate) as count_hire_date
 FROM Faculty
GROUP BY ROLLUP(HireDate);
```

Trying to get something like this:

```
hire_date  count_hire_date
1995       10
1996       20
1997       30
TOTAL      60
```

Do I use some sort of cast in SQL server or what do I write to fix this syntax error and get this to work in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in the case expression and ROLLUP, it should be like this:

```
    SELECT (CASE when  GROUPING(HireDate) = 0 then CONVERT(varchar(50),HireDate) else 'TOTAL' end) HireDate,
    count(HireDate) as count_hire_date
    FROM Faculty
    GROUP BY HireDate WITH ROLLUP
```

and please refer to this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178544.aspx

Comment: That still gives me a syntax error.  Do I keep the end in the case statement with SQL Server?

Comment: I'm still getting the `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.` error. :(

Comment: Try this please:
SELECT (CASE when  GROUPING(HireDate) = 0 then CONVERT(varchar(50),HireDate) else 'TOTAL' end) HireDate,
    count(HireDate) as count_hire_date
    FROM Faculty
    GROUP BY HireDate WITH ROLLUP